# The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. returning 403

Tags: wcf

I'm getting the error while make call to the service "The HTTP request was forbidden with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'."

actually im hosting this service in plesk, and in the plesk Anonymous authentication is enabled.

WCF Config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="SampleService.ServiceContracts.SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpConfig" contract="SampleService.ServiceContracts.ISampleService"></endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="basicHttpConfig" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" receiveTimeout="00:00:10">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2000000" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"></serviceDebug>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpBinding" scheme="https"  />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Client

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://samplewcf.packletsgo.com/ServiceContracts/SampleService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService"
        contract="ServiceReference1.ISampleService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISampleService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 0):

This error typically occurred when the server authenticates the client with a certificate, nothing business with your current scenario. If the certificate's trust relationship between the client and server is not established, this error will occur.
I doubt whether the client configuration is automatically generated by using the above server configuration. In the above configuration, we should add an https bind to the website on the server-side in order to suit the `Basichttpbinding` with transport security mode. On the client-side, we should trust the server certificate before calling the service, or we will get the below similar error.

> “The underlying connection is closed: trust cannot be established for
>   the SSL/TLS security channel”.

In short, we need to validate whether the remote certificate is valid before communicating with the server.
At last, why does the service contain the following fragment, and do you use the virtual path?

> https://localhost/SampleService/AuthService/AuthService.svc

I would like to know more details about how the error occurred. Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: https://samplewcf.packletsgo.com/ServiceContracts/SampleService.svc

This is my sample service, you can check using your client.

Comment: i edited new client and server web config in the question and thank you for comment.

Comment: @ManiLancer , This should be the firewall/anti-virus software problem. On my side, I try to reproduce your issue, while the client works perfectly(after trust the server certificate). Please check the network settings to see if our IP is in the blacklist.

Comment: there is no black listed IP's, and can you able to call the service method??

Comment: I didn't lie to you, I can call the service method normally. You can test it on two machines inside the intranet LAN.

Comment: sorry for bothering u and late reply, but im still getting the error. from the below service url

[sample service](https://sampleservice.packletsgo.com/ServiceContracts/SampleService.svc)

this is the error im getting [error image](https://ibb.co/jbTPLxc)

its automatically created config [Client Config](https://ibb.co/L93hcSS) @Abraham Qian
`try {
          SampleService.SampleServiceClient samp = new SampleService.SampleServiceClient();
                samp.GetData(4);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }`

Comment: It's ok. You can host the above projects in IIS. Then use a self-signed certificate to ensure transport layer security. I did get the same error as you. But I host the above service locally and then call it. Everything works fine. Thereby I think it's a network issue.

Comment: yes, first i hosted the service in shared hosting, then i tried azure app service its working fine. thank you.